# many cache calls in development log - how to prevent them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4.2 app that has literally hundreds of calls like this:

```
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "albums".* FROM "albums" WHERE (albumable_type='ItemProfile' and albumable_id=33333)  ORDER BY "albums"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "assets" WHERE "assets"."album_id" = $1 AND "assets"."is_enabled" = $2  [["album_id", 19182], ["is_enabled", true]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "albums".* FROM "albums" WHERE (albumable_type='ItemProfile' and albumable_id=33333)  ORDER BY "albums"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "assets".* FROM "assets" WHERE "assets"."album_id" = $1 AND "assets"."is_enabled" = $2  ORDER BY "assets"."position" ASC LIMIT 1  [["album_id", 19182], ["is_enabled", true]]
```

Two questions:

- Are these calls actually being made (my understanding is no due to "CACHE")?
- Is there a way to tell Rails that it already has this info and doesn't need to check for it? Like hundreds of times seems liek a bug on my end

### edit #1

so the problem is that there is stuff like the following:

```
  def instore_image
    album.enabled_assets.first
  end
```

and

```
  def image_600w
    Rails.logger.info("#9797 here is instore_image_url")
    instore_image.asset.url(:fixed_width600)
    Rails.logger.info("#9898 here is instore_image_url")
  end
```

The image_600w is calling a round of sql calls (whether cached or not). It seems like to prevent this from happening I need to set an instance variable on the object.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the section on [Caching with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) in Rails Guides:

> 1.5 SQL Caching
>
> Query caching is a Rails feature that caches the result set returned
>   by each query so that if Rails encounters the same query again for
>   that request, it will use the cached result set as opposed to running
>   the query against the database again.

So these queries are actually being made by your application, however ActiveRecord intercepts these queries and prevents SQL query by directly delivering from Query cache.

> Is there a way to tell Rails that it already has this info and doesn't need to check for it? Like hundreds of times seems liek a bug on my end.

Yes, Rails is already doing the best it can by reusing cached query results. You can use [bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) to identify N+1 queries and other similar inefficient database usage patterns in your application.

Comment: thx for answer - I dug a bit deeper and can see what the problem is (see edit #1) - it looks like I need to set an instance variable explicitly in this case or some other sol'n to prevent rails from thinking it needs to go back to db (whether cached or not).

Comment: @timpone I am facing the same issue. Can you please share the changes you made to solve this issue? Thanks